# Adobe Photoshop- Resizing images proportionally

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have two images- front and side view of a person's face but they're not in proportion to one another. How do I resize them so the facial features are aligned? I can't seem to find any resources for that.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vu6jdSaSVyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily the basics of what they are doing there is really quite simple.

1. Open your front facing image.
2. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> if you don't have rulers turned on already.
3. Click the top ruler and drag down several guides to mark the major facial features - centre of eyes, bottom of nose, chin etc. Whatever you think will help.
4. Click the side ruler and drag right to again mark the eye centres, edge of face etc. Remember too many guides = confusion
5. Open the side facing image and drag it onto the front facing image. This makes a new layer.(It will help quality if this image is a similar size of course, or bigger...just not smaller)
6. At this point I would lower the opacity of this side facing image a little, maybe 80% or 90%
7. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> top open the Transform tool.
8. Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while you drag the corners, or rotate this image to line up with the other image, and the guides. (Holding shift makes sure you don't change the ratio of the image).

The rest of that video is a little bit more tricky! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your images must have been taken from about the same altitude. Otherwise you are out of luck. Only small perspective corrections are possible without causing intolerable distortion to the shape.

Photos for this purpose must not have noticeable lens distortion nor exaggerated nose due short camera distance. The focal lenght should be at least 100 mm when scaled to 35 mm. Refer photography books if this sounds strange.

Do not expect automatic matching. You must do it manually in Photoshop.

Find the layers panel (Windows > Layers) You need it.

Copy  one photo to the clipboard and paste it as a new layer onto the other. Copy and paste that one which has smaller pixel dimensions. You can also make a selection and copy only the essential part of the photo.

Make the upper layer partially transparent by decreasing its opacity in the layers panel Otherwise you cannot see both photos at the same time.

By the arrow tool can

- move the layers
- resize (hold Shift to keep the aspect ratio)

The arrow affects to the layer which is selected in the layers panel.

In Edit menu you have more possiblities:

Edit > Transform > Free transform allow both rotating and shifting
Edit > Transform > Distort allows to move the cornes independently. This is needed if you must correct the perspective, too.
Edit > Transform > Warp or Puppet Warp allows (in theory) to match a little different face expressions.

When you have aligned the photos well enough, return the opacity to 100%.

Crop the image if it has a big exessive area

Save the photo

- as PSD just for the case you notice later some mistake
- as PNG or JPG if you need the profiles separately

In the layers panel disable the layer that must be invisible.